# Antd4 select maintain text selection in text area when selecting font

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using antd4 select as a font family/ font size selector. So when highlight text I would like to preserve the text selection highlighting and maintaining focus on the text area when selecting another font.
I have tried to preventDefault() on mousedown, but that didn't work as expected as you can see from the sandbox below. Thanks for any help.

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-swartz-scy6z?file=/src/App.js)

EDIT: This was working with antd v3 select but they rewrote it and is no longer working.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, I modified your [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-night-v8udn) and now text stills highlited and focus is on textarea. In brief:

1. Added a ref to `textarea` called `this.nameInput`.
2. I replaced `onMouseDown` function with `onChange`.
3. On function `onChange` I move the focus into textarea by using `this.nameInput.focus()`

Comment: Unfortunately not exactly what I was looking for. I am trying to manipulate the selected text so merely refocusing on change is not the result I was looking for. Thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: Ciao, try to explain me better what you are looking for. What do you mean when you say "Manipulation"?